# Does react framework based website hides code in browser at client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frameworks

My web developer telling me that react framework based website hides code at the client side. I have website where seeing the source code displays only few line of code nothing else like the body of the website page. Please help. You can find the website at https://raybaby.us/

Any help will be appreciated as I'm struggling with source code regarding SEO of website.

Comment: Any code that is running in the browser - is visible to the user if they want to see it. That's the nature of javascript. As such, you shouldn't store any sensitive data in frontend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of your question - I think what you're referring to is the rendering of the HTML.

So yes typically what happens on a frontend-only react app is you will have an html file that looks like this:

```
<html> 
   <head> 
      <!-- some meta information here, perhaps a base css style--> 
   </head> 

   <body>  
      <div id = "root">
           <!-- this element is left empty, 
               and then react will use javascript to populate it
           --> 
      </div> 
      <script src=...> <!-- the react script--> </script> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

And then what happens is that the page loads, then the javascript runs, and manipulates the dom and populates it with your content.

From an SEO perspective, (and I certainly don't have any indepth experience with SEO), my understanding is that once upon of time this would have been a bad thing, because the web crawlers wouldn't run the Javascript - they'd see the empty HTML only.

However, my understanding [is that this is no longer the case](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/seo-vs-react-is-it-neccessary-to-render-react-pages-in-the-backend-74ce5015c0c9?gi=e5c5af8b4280).

However - if you do want content to be rendered without have the javascript run - you can use [server side rendering.](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-reacts-server-side-render-de335d408fe4) What SSR will do is use React to render static HTML on the backend, providing the pre-existing HTML and CSS boilerplate to exist, before the javascript starts running.

(If you're interested, I've personally found [this project](https://github.com/rherwig/template-react-ssr) a really good template for SSR).

It's up to you to do some research on whether you need this for your SEO, but that's the basics of it.